# PHP using curl POST data in json - REST api not working

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

```
function processCurlJsonrequest($URL, $fieldString)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->_cookie_file_path);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->_cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fieldString));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $resulta = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    return $resulta;
}
$data_string = array("title" => "jdsdfds","url"=>"sdfdfd","date"=>"2014-01-30");
processCurlJsonrequest('http://localhost/articles',$data_string);
```

Hi,
I am using REST api post method, type JSON to post data by using curl function. But its not working at all and no output is showing.

I did test this by using Fiefox plugin RESTClient.
its works fine, able to post data into my database.
I am stuck when using PHP curl method to post data. Above is one of the example i took from internet but still not working. Need advice from senior.

Comment: Hi, you could possibly do this without using the POST method, as you can send a request to the server as a GET, just url_encode the query then url_decode it at the endpoint from client ?

Comment: Hi, the thing is i need to post data not to get data.correct me if i get you wrong

Comment: Hi, its possible to send data with the $_GET['']; parameters as well :), i for example use it do create an user on a remote DB

Comment: is the url http or https?

Comment: its http -> http://localhost/articles. sorry i dont get you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Handle POST requests to /articles
$app->post('/articles', function () use ($app) {
    try {
        // get and decode JSON request body
        $request = $app->request();
        $body = $request->getBody();
        $input = json_decode($body);

        $count = count($input);

        for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {

            // store article record
            $article = R::dispense('articles');
            $article->title = (string)$input[$x]->title;
            $article->url = (string)$input[$x]->url;
            $article->date = (string)$input[$x]->date;
            $id = R::store($article);

            // return JSON-encoded response body
            $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            echo json_encode(R::exportAll($article));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $app->response()->status(400);
        $app->response()->header('X-Status-Reason', $e->getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: the error is line 142 is - >$article->title = (string)$input[$x]->title;

Comment: Add some debugging code, like `var_dump(json_decode($body));` to figure out whats wrong with the data. Sometimes its better to work with an array (second parm of json_decode), so
`var_dump(json_decode($body, true));` and `$input   = json_decode($body, true);  + $article->title = $input[$x]['title'];`.

Comment: Hi Jens, 
var_dump saved my life. its able to retrieve the data when var dump. Then i realise its not in array format. so i did change by adding Array to this  $input   = array(json_decode($body,true));.
now my code is working and data able to save into my db.

Comment: Unfortunately i had another problem.
if i has array list like this : 
 $data_string = array("title" => "test12345,test12345","url"=>"htttp,http2","date"=>"2014-01-30,2014-01-31");
The data inserting only the first array position not the second as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know that, from the example above, the url is a standard http request yet the code references ssl. Also, you set the `RETURNTRANSFER` yet do not echo / print the result - only printing the error if there is one. I have found that it is essential to have a copy of `cacert.pem` - [download from here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
 ~ edit the path according to your server config. If the site is not https then it gets ignored anyway.

```
 function processCurlJsonrequest($URL, $fieldString) {

    $cacert=realpath( 'c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem' );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if( parse_url( $URL,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fieldString ) );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    $results=curl_exec($ch);
    $errors=curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return array(
        'results'=>$results,
        'errors'=>$errors
    );
}
```

Notices that the function returns an array, you would need to account for that when dealing with the response....

```
$data_string = array("title" => "jdsdfds","url"=>"sdfdfd","date"=>"2014-01-30");
$response = processCurlJsonrequest('http://localhost/articles',$data_string);

echo '<pre>',print_r($response,true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: Hi RamRider,  
i received this error.
 
Array
(
    [results] => 

Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpstorm_workspace\slim\index.php on line 142


    [errors] => 
)

Comment: This error refers, I presume, to the code you recently posted above rather than the editing curl request function? I think what you need to do in your code above is include "true" in the json_decode call, viz: `json_decode($body,true)` ~ that will convert to an array rather than a json object

Comment: i did that -json_decode($body,true) and the errors is gone. but still no luck. data not save into db and no output has display
Array
(
    [results] => 
    [errors] => 
)

Comment: is there anything printed to screen? I would suggest using some debug statements in the function that handles the POST request to see what is happening.Does the db get updated?

Comment: the output shows :  Array ( [results] => [errors] => ) . its empty
Nop.its not updating in DB

Comment: is the request actually reaching the script that does the processing? Put a `print_r($_POST)` statement before the call to your function in "C:\xampp\htdocs\phpstorm_workspace\slim\index.php" and see if there is anything displayed.

Comment: weird. After i done this ->json_decode($body,true). 
I tested using the firefox RESTClient ,the data not inserting in DB and its shows this error :


    Status Code: 400 Bad Request
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 0
    Content-Type: text/html
    Date: Tue, 08 Sep 2015 21:58:09 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.28
    X-Status-Reason: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you are right. its not capturing data. Array is empty.

Comment: The header "Content-Type" was sending a bad value - remove that and hopefully all should be ok

Answer (score 0):

this is something ive used if you already know every parameter that is going to be added.

client.php:

```
<?php
$Username = "TestUsername";
$Password = "Password123";
$Email = "mail@email.tld";


$Url = "http://localhost/your/path/server.php?Username=$Username&Password=$Password&Email=$Email";


//send request:
$Client = curl_init($Url);


curl_setopt($Client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


//response:
$Response = curl_exec($Client);


//decode:
$Result = json_decode($Response);

if($Result->Status==200){

$Output .= "Success, $Result->StatusMessage ($Result->Status)<br/> Data:<br/>";
$Output .= "Username: " . $Result->Information->Username . "<br/>";
$Output .= "Password: " . $Result->Information->Password . "<br/>";
$Output .= "Email: " . $Result->Information->Email . "<br/>";

echo $Output;



}
else{
echo "an error occured.";
}
```

Server.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");


$Username = $_GET['Username'];
$Password = $_GET['Password'];
$Email = $_GET['Email'];

$HTTPSTATUS = 200;
$HTTP_MESSAGE = "RECORD ADDED.";


$Info = array(
'Username' => $Username,
'Password' => $Password,
'Email' => $Email
);

header("HTTP/1.1 $HTTPSTATUS $HTTP_MESSAGE");


$Response['Status'] = $HTTPSTATUS;
$Response['StatusMessage'] = $HTTP_MESSAGE;
$Response['Information'] = $Info;


$Return = json_encode($Response);

echo $Return;
```

This would be the result:

```
   Success, RECORD ADDED. (200)data:
    Username: TestUsername
    Password: Password123
    Email: mail@email.tld
```

Now, im no expert at this, but this works like a charm for me.

Comment: HI Kris,
thanks for your reply. Now i noticed that its actually error coming from my api request got error. please see my post.

Answer (score 0):

I did change code a bit from :

```
// store article record
 $article = R::dispense('articles');
 $article->title = (string)$input[$x]->title;
 $article->url = (string)$input[$x]->url;
 $article->date = (string)$input[$x]->date;
 $id = R::store($article);
```

to this :

```
   // store article record
         $article = R::dispense('articles');
         $article->title = $input[$x]['title'];
         $article->url   = $input[$x]['url'];
         $article->date  = $input[$x]['date'];
         $id = R::store($article);
```

Now I'm able to post from Firefox rest-client plugin. able to post and create data in db. But still its not working when I tried from the PHP curl code.

Comment: RamRider, i did removed the content type but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
$url = 'Your url';  
$args = 'Your argumnts';

  $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($args));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
      return $result ? json_decode($result, true) : false;
```